# How can I merge rows of a table that records history of changes in order to obtain what a row looked like at a specific moment?

Tags: postgresql, select, postgresql-13

I have the following 2 SELECTs:

```
SELECT * FROM public.app_user WHERE id = 'e31b55bf';
+--------+----+-----------+-----+-----+--------------------------+
|id      |name|email      |role |bio  |created_at                |
+--------+----+-----------+-----+-----+--------------------------+
|e31b55bf|Jon |jon@app.com|admin|Hello|2022-01-01 00:00:00.000000|
+--------+----+-----------+-----+-----+--------------------------+

SELECT * FROM history.app_user WHERE id = 'e31b55bf';
+--------+----+--------------+--------+----+--------------------------+
|id      |name|email         |role    |bio |updated_at                |
+--------+----+--------------+--------+----+--------------------------+
|e31b55bf|ASDF|test          |NULL    |NULL|2022-01-02 00:00:00.000000|
|e31b55bf|Test|test@gmail.com|basic   |NULL|2022-01-03 00:00:00.000000|
|e31b55bf|NULL|NULL          |standard|asdf|2022-01-04 00:00:00.000000|
|e31b55bf|NULL|NULL          |mod     |NULL|2022-01-05 00:00:00.000000|
+--------+----+--------------+--------+----+--------------------------+
```

`public.app_user` contains the users of my app and `history.app_user` contains a record of previous values of the rows of the first. In the example above, the user `e31b55bf` was a mod instead of an admin before the 5th of January, an standard user with the bio "asdf" before the 4th, a basic user named "Test" with the email "test@gmail.com" before the 3rd...

I want to come up with a SELECT or a FUNCTION that will tell me what the row looked like at a specific point in time. I believe I have already accomplished it, but my solution looks more complex than it should be. It's also tedious to translate it to other tables: say `public.project` and `history.project`, for example, where the columns are totally different. I believe a cleaner, easier to read and write solution exists. Can a SQL wizard help me here?

My current solution consists of overriding the values of the current row at `public.app_user` with the non-null values of this:

```
SELECT t.uuid,
       t1.name,
       t2.email,
       t3.role,
       t4.bio
FROM (
     SELECT uuid,
            MIN(CASE WHEN name IS NOT NULL THEN updated_at END)       AS name_date,
            MIN(CASE WHEN email IS NOT NULL THEN updated_at END)      AS email_date,
            MIN(CASE WHEN role IS NOT NULL THEN updated_at END)       AS role_date,
            MIN(CASE WHEN bio IS NOT NULL THEN updated_at END)        AS bio_date
     FROM history.app_user
     WHERE updated_at > '2022-01-03 12:00:00.000000' -- Date to check
     GROUP BY uuid
     ) t
     LEFT JOIN history.app_user t1 ON t1.updated_at = t.name_date
     LEFT JOIN history.app_user t2 ON t2.updated_at = t.email_date
     LEFT JOIN history.app_user t3 ON t3.updated_at = t.role_date
     LEFT JOIN history.app_user t4 ON t4.updated_at = t.bio_date
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1 : window function**

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (uuid)
     , uuid
     , (array_agg(name) FILTER (WHERE name IS NOT NULL) OVER w)[1] AS name
     , (array_agg(email) FILTER (WHERE email IS NOT NULL) OVER w)[1] AS email
     , (array_agg(role) FILTER (WHERE role IS NOT NULL) OVER w)[1] AS role
     , (array_agg(bio) FILTER (WHERE bio IS NOT NULL) OVER w)[1] AS bio 
  FROM history.app_user
 WHERE updated_at > '2022-01-03 12:00:00.000000' -- Date to check
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY uuid ORDER BY updated_at)
```

`array_agg()` is an [aggregate function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) which is used as a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) here.

`FILTER (WHERE condition)` is used to exclude the NULL values from the selected rows.

The window is a subset of rows associated to the current row as described in the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html), ie all the existing rows with the same `uuid` as stated in the `PARTITION BY` clause. The `ORDER BY` clause allows to put the earliest non-null value in the first position of the resulting array and which is selected by `[1]`.

The main issue of using here window functions is that we get as many rows as the ones filtered by the `WHERE` clause. The `DISTINCT ON ()` clause excludes the redundant rows from the final result.

The second solution based on the same function used as an `aggregate function` instead of a `window function` is more accurate in our case.

**Solution 2 : aggregate function**

```
SELECT uuid
     , (array_agg(name ORDER BY updated_at) FILTER (WHERE name IS NOT NULL))[1] AS name
     , (array_agg(email ORDER BY updated_at) FILTER (WHERE email IS NOT NULL))[1] AS email
     , (array_agg(role ORDER BY updated_at) FILTER (WHERE role IS NOT NULL))[1] AS role
     , (array_agg(bio ORDER BY updated_at) FILTER (WHERE bio IS NOT NULL))[1] AS bio 
  FROM history.app_user
 WHERE updated_at > '2022-01-03 12:00:00.000000' -- Date to check
 GROUP BY uuid
```

Comment: This looks much better than my solution. Could you explain why this works? I've never used WINDOW and PARTITION.

Comment: I've updated the answer with some explanations regarding the window functions, and a second solution based on aggregate functions and which is more accurate.

Comment: From what I can understand, both solutions provide the same result so they are equally accurate. Do you mean performant? Is the second solution usually faster because it has less redundant operations?

Comment: "Accurate" means the solution 2 better fits your need, ie having one resulting row per uuid. Then I would think the second solution is also more performant but the best way to check would be you to execute `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` for both solutions and to share the results.